# how to successfully execute a python script that contains webscraping codes with pyinstaller

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, web-scraping, pyinstaller

i developed a tkinter GUI that track covid19 in my country. i converted the python script to .exe using pyinstaller. when i lunch the .exe, it says "failed to execute script". Note: i am connected to the internet before launching. how can i make my code execute successfully pls?

```
######CODE#######
def getCase():
    URL="https://covid19.ncdc.gov.ng/"
    data= get_html_data(URL)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(data.content, "html.parser")
    lis= soup.find("div", {"class":"col-md-12 col-xl-3"}).find_all("div",{"class":"card-body"})

    sec= soup.find_all("div",{"class":"col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3"})
    all_de=""
    for proces in sec:
        text= proces.find("h6",{"class":"text-white"}).get_text()
        count= proces.find("span").get_text()

####GUI####
label2= tk.Label(root,text=getCase(),bg="#9999A1",font=("Bahnschrift SemiLight", 20))
label2.pack()
```

Comment: You need to add `.mainloop()` at the end.

Comment: Make sure the packed exe contains all the required packages.  BTW there should be other error messages other than *"failed to execute script"* if it is executed in a console.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i used "**pyinstaller --onefile --windowed app.py**" to convert the script to exe. after conversion, no console was displayed when lunching the app and the app eventually dispalyed  "**failed to execute script**". Note: the "**root.mainloop()**" is already there before i converted